# What is the intuition behind the term Transitive for verbs?

Tags: semantics, transitivity

Why is a verb that takes an object called **transitive**? Why does that term make sense?

The way I see it is that it extends its action to an object rather than limits it within the subject. I take this notion from the Arabic terms of intransitive (لازِم) meaning *contained* and (مُتَعَدّي) meaning *transceding* (I might have just made up that word). However, this notion has no sense of transition. Hence the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The grammatical sense of the word "[transitive](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transitive)" comes from the Latin *[transitivus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transitivus#Latin)*, which as you imply the idea of going (*itus*) across (*trans*). This is calqued from Hellenistic Greek μεταβατικός.

The most well known early use comes from the late Roman grammarian [Priscian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priscian), who wrote the "Institutes of Grammar" (*Institutiones Grammaticae*) in the 6th century CE. Therein he writes that in transitive verbs the sense crossed over from one person to another, and explained that such verbs usually occurred with oblique cases ([page 552 of the edition, PDF page 602](https://ia802606.us.archive.org/29/items/PriscianiInstitutionumGrammaticarumLibri/PriscianiInstitutionumGrammaticarumLibriI-xiihertz.1855_text.pdf)):

> nam μεταβατικά dicuntur, id est transitiva, quae ab alia ad alia transeunt personam, in quibus solent || obliqui casus adiungi verbis.